# "DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries" Error after implementing custom identity class

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to create user registration form on .net core using DbFirst approach. 
I created a table in database. Created .net core project using User Authentication(built in identity). Then I did Scaffolding. After Filling fields with proper values and posting the request, I get this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> SqlException: Invalid column name 'AccessFailedCount'. Invalid column
>   name 'ConcurrencyStamp'. Invalid column name 'LockoutEnabled'. Invalid
>   column name 'LockoutEnd'. Invalid column name 'NormalizedEmail'.
>   Invalid column name 'NormalizedUserName'. Invalid column name
>   'PasswordHash'. Invalid column name 'PhoneNumber'. Invalid column name
>   'PhoneNumberConfirmed'. Invalid column name 'SecurityStamp'. Invalid
>   column name 'TwoFactorEnabled'. Invalid column name 'UserName'.
>
> DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See
>   the inner exception for details.

The fields mentioned above are in read-only file called IdentityUser(the one I am inheriting from). It's read-only so I can not delete any fields from it.

This is my Register IActionResult:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {


        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        var errors = ModelState.Where(c => c.Value.Errors.Count > 0).Select(c => c.Value).ToList();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {


            var user = new User
            {
                Name = model.Name,
                Email = model.Email,
                Address = model.Address,
                PersonalId = model.PersonalId,
                Country = model.Country,
                MobilePhone = model.MobilePhone,
                BirthDate = model.BirthDate,

            };

            _context.User.Add(user);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Home", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);





                return RedirectToAction("RegisterConfirm");

            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

I am guessing, that problem is that the fields mentioned in **IdentityUser** are empty and that is why I am getting the error but maybe I am wrong. 
User.cs

```
public partial class User :IdentityUser<int>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string PersonalId { get; set; }
        public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public byte[] Idimage { get; set; }
        public bool? EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
        public bool? Smsconfirmed { get; set; }
    }
```

IdentityUser

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Represents a user in the identity system
    //
    // Type parameters:
    //   TKey:
    //     The type used for the primary key for the user.
    public class IdentityUser<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser`1.
        public IdentityUser();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser`1.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   userName:
        //     The user name.
        public IdentityUser(string userName);

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the date and time, in UTC, when any user lockout ends.
        //
        // Remarks:
        //     A value in the past means the user is not locked out.
        public virtual DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a flag indicating if two factor authentication is enabled for this
        //     user.
        [PersonalData]
        public virtual bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a flag indicating if a user has confirmed their telephone address.
        [PersonalData]
        public virtual bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a telephone number for the user.
        [ProtectedPersonalData]
        public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     A random value that must change whenever a user is persisted to the store
        public virtual string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     A random value that must change whenever a users credentials change (password
        //     changed, login removed)
        public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a salted and hashed representation of the password for this user.
        public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a flag indicating if a user has confirmed their email address.
        [PersonalData]
        public virtual bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the normalized email address for this user.
        public virtual string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the email address for this user.
        [ProtectedPersonalData]
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the normalized user name for this user.
        public virtual string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the user name for this user.
        [ProtectedPersonalData]
        public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the primary key for this user.
        [PersonalData]
        public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a flag indicating if the user could be locked out.
        public virtual bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the number of failed login attempts for the current user.
        public virtual int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Returns the username for this user.
        public override string ToString();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE : Just found out that I can not see Identity Tables in my database. That's another problem I guess.**

Comment: I believe you need to run database migration using `Update-Database` command.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I did the migration. Can't update database because table named "someName" already exists in database. I created that table by hand in database because of my dbFirst approach.

Comment: Your database and DbContext are not sync up. You need to modify your database to add the missing table and fields or, run `add-migration` and `update-database` to sync up the database.